# Uploading a game to Gamejolt (no download)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been working with game code for two months in Unity and really want to upload something to gamejolt. So far, I can upload downloadable files. I don't know how to make a .html file, so I can't make a no-download version.

Sorry if my question doesn't make much sense, but I'd love any help I can get. Thank in advance!

I've tried looking through youtube and google, but I can't find much of anything.

na

Goal:    uploading a game (I made in unity) to gamejolt that doesn't require a download to play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When building your game, select WebGL, then Switch platform. Adjust all the settings in Player Settings (in the WebGL, the square with a 5 in it) then you can build.

This will give you a folder with a .html file in it, that you just have to open in your browser to play (same goes for Gamejolt)

Comment: You're welcome ! Please set the answer as accepted if it solved your problem :)